# How to password protect a image directory with a web.config

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, web-config

How would I set a directory to where only authenticated users could access the files?

In other words I need to make sure that only people that are logged in can access the images and other person data with a web.config.

What are the settings?

Here is what I've got so far but it does not stop users that are not logged.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

---

My web.config file with most of the information removed. If you could place that configuration info where it goes so that no one that is on my site can access a folder called users unless they are logged on.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="cnn.config" />
  <appSettings configSource="app.config" />
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.5" targetFramework="4.5" encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework45" />
    <authentication configSource="authentication.config" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership configSource="membership.config" />
    <roleManager configSource="roles.config" />
    <profile configSource="profile.config" />
      <!--<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>-->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this article: [HOW TO: Control Authorization Permissions in an ASP.NET Application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871)

In short you can set folder permissions like this:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="images">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users ="?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I've place that in my web.config in the root director. the Images folder is under the root directory and I still can access the image directly with a url pointing right to an image in the image folder. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you set up any form of authentication in your web.config? Also see the HOW TO url.

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="xxxxxx"  protection ="All" timeout="1440" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" />
</authentication>

Comment: Did you place all your allows after your deny's? Note that the config reads from top to bottom. For more examples you might also have a look at: http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx if you stil don't get it to work can you post the relevant part from your web.config?

Comment: I cannot get it man. I've posted a trimmed down version of my web.config. If you could see what I wrote about it and place that config info in the correct location so that no one on my site can access a folder called users unless they're logged in. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try to place it after </system.web> and before </configuration>? If it doesn't work could you try to put: <authorization> <deny users="*"/> </authorization> to see if it has any effect? If still you can't get it to work could you include the relevant external configs in your example config so I can try it myself?

Comment: according to this  http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/836472  Forms based authentication *only* protects files that are handled by aspnet - not only are your gifs available but so are your jpgs, pngs, htmls, javascripts and every other file type that's not routed through the aspnet dll.

Or failing that you could use url rewriting for instance:

You request:
/images/bla.gif

Which is rewritten to:
/get.aspx?file=/images/bla.gif